# Is there a mechanism to harvest a value from an instance created in a cloud formation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation template that's launching a sequence of 3 EC2 instances. The first instance generates an encryption key that the other 2 instances will need in order to communicate with the first.

Looking for a mechanism I can use so that the cloud formation template can launch the first instance, run a script to create the key, and harvest the value to pass to the next two nodes to launch them.  I can use a waitcondition to allow for the delay, but have not been able to get the key string back cleanly.

Do have a way to do it - but it seems like a hack:
 - Attach the first server to a role with the rights to write to an S3 bucket; have the instance save it there.
 - attach the second the third servers to a role with the rights to read said bucket; pick it back up.

Is there a best practice I'm missing?

Comment: How are you generating the key?  Have you considered using KMS?

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post on something that might help here:

http://krogebry.blogspot.com/2014/12/chef-aws-kms_13.html

Basically I'm using KMS to host a special key that I use for decryption Chef data bags.

In your case I might modify something like this to create the key in CF, or have a pre-launch task to do the key generation, then pass the key data down to the clients that are created.  This way you're tapping into the utility of KMS without having to actually store the special key in S3.